# Custom ItemDecoration class is not drawing divider on last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have a custom ItemDecoration class that is not drawing the last divider for my last item.

Custom Decoration class:

```
public class DividerTest extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable mDivider;

    public DividerTest(Context context) {
        mDivider = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_horizontal);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);

        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list, this);
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
DividerTest divider = new DividerTest(this);
mRecycler.addItemDecoration(divider);
mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: divi]

When I use the default DividerItemDecoration class, it works:

```
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list, this);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecycler.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

Why is my custom item decoration class not drawing my last divider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me add implementation to `getItemOffsets`on your ItemDecoration class

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    if (parent.getAdapter() != null && position == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    }
}
```