# RecyclerView.ItemDecoration with a custom view, only on a specific element of the list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to add a RecyclerView.ItemDecoration with a custom View inside it, on specific elements of the list

For example on a list with 10 elements, i want to show the decoration on item 4 and 7.

Comment: Check the adapter position and add the layout on that positiion.

Comment: if(position==4){
view.visibilty.Gone
view2.visibilty.Visible}

Comment: I had to have the view inside the list element, and that is not the case.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569505/custom-itemdecoration-class-is-not-drawing-divider-on-last-item and from there in the `onDraw` method you have the recycler so you can get your adapter. You might need the adapter for custom data `adapter.hasSpecialDivider(position)`